# What is the proper use of footsep?

Tags: overleaf

I am trying to work with the margins in the default overleaf editor, but am getting an error.

I follow the overleaf guide for margins here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/page_size_and_margins

It states:

> **footsep**
>
> Separation between the bottom of the text (baseline) and the
> top of the footnote. Element 11 in the figure.

I use:

```
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=1in,headsep=0pt,headheight=0pt}
```

and it works, then I use

```
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=1in,headsep=0pt,headheight=0pt,footsep=0cm}
```

and the error is

```
Package keyval Error: footsep undefined
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes} % times font
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=1in,headsep=0pt,headheight=0pt,footsep=0cm}

\title{EX}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: The corresponding option name in `geometry` is `footskip`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ That is the option shown below footsep in the overleaf doc

Comment: Please provide a MWE.

Comment: @Steradiant example following the overleaf documentation that fails is updated

Comment: It seems like `footsep` is not defined in the `geometry` [package](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf). Look at the linked documentation and find the actual parameter you want to change. Probably `footskip` is the one you're looking for.

Comment: That package link seems to make it clear. Overleaf documentation is wrong, it seems like they mixed up paramater names footskip with footnotesep

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf Support here. Sorry for this, it turns out this was a typo in the Overleaf LaTeX documentation. We corrected this already. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @yo' Hi Tom, thanks for the follow-up and notice! Its great to see you active on the community and checking these posts out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `footsep` is not defined in the `geometry` [package](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf). Look at the linked documentation and find the parameter you want to change. Probably `footskip` is the one you're looking for.